# Exception in thread "pool-71-thread-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: android, android-studio, jvm

I'm working on last version of Android Studio and create Junit Test.
However I can't launch it. I always receive a Java heap space error.
I use the environment variable STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS to set the path to my vm.options file.
In this file, I put the following :
-Xmx256m
-XX:MaxHeapSize=256m

I don't understand why I receive this.
I'm on MAC machine.

Thx in advance